# Update Cloud Firestore Collection Based on "Master Collection"

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an iOS application to help users who collect figurines keep track of their figurines and see realtime price information.

I have two collections:

1. The "master" collection

   - This is essentially a catalog of thousands of figurines users can select to add to their collection. It has information about each item, such as Artist, Original Price, Barcode, Year, Comments, etc.
2. The "user" collection

   - This contains documents for each user. Each of these "user" documents has a sub-collection with documents for each figurine they have added to their collection.

Currently, if a user wants to add a new item to their personal collection, they go to the "master" collection UITableView and swipe to add an item. The item document is basically copied from the "master" collection and a new document in the user sub-collection is created. They can then go to a UITableView that displays the items they have added. They have the option to add their own information about the item, such as comments, date bought, date sold, price bought, etc.

My question: How can I sync information between the document in the user collection/sub-collection and the document in the main collection? Say the "Market Price" for an item has gone up, so I update the main collection database. How can I get this price change to display in all users' collections?

I assume by using Cloud Functions, but I wanted to post here in case there was an easier method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a good use for Cloud Functions.  Create an onUpdate trigger for your `/users{uid}/figurines/{figurineId}` collection and then use that to copy the updated data to the master.

You can either copy specific fields or you can check for differences by examining `event.data.data()` and `event.data.previous.data()`

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.updateMaster = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{uid}/figurines/{figurineId}')
  .onUpdate(event => {
    var newData = event.data.data();
    var oldData = event.data.previous.data();
    var updateData = {};

    if (oldData.price != newData.price) {updateData.price = newData.price}
    // Add any more changes that you may want to compare / update below...

    // Then...
    return db
      .collection('master')
      .doc(event.params.figurineId)
      .update(updateData).then(response => {

      console.log('We updated figurine', event.params.figurineId);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('There was an error', err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Happy to help.  What this solution doesn't allow for is copying the updated price back to every user who has a particular figurine in their collection.

Comment: So if I changed the marketPrice field of a figurine in the master collection (.document('figurines/figurineId}), is there an expedient way to update the "marketPrice" field in every user's collection (.document('users/{uid}/figurines/{figurineId})? I will be rolling out updates roughly four times a year where I update prices for around 10,000 figurines.

Comment: Basically, I am more interested in the opposite action. I would like to send out information from the master to each user's figurine document.

Comment: There is currently no way of updating several sub-collection across various parent documents.  This is a requested feature, so we may see it sometime in the future.  The 2 solutions that I can think of for this are either to a) not include changeable information in the users figurine documents and always get them from the master or b) create a Cloud Function to get all users, then iterate through each of them, checking their figurine sub-collection.  The latter solution is not widely scalable, depending on the number of users.  Cloud Functions timeout after 2 minutes.

Comment: I understand. Well, I will hope that this feature is introduced at some point. Not being able to include changeable information in the user's figurine documents is unfortunately not an option. I suppose I could also make two pull requests (one from the master, one from the collector's figurine document) to display on a View, but this doesn't seem efficient.

The second solution you describe might work, since I want updates to be quarterly.

Comment: When you get all documents in a list, you can get all of the data, except the value.  When a user selects an item, get the price from the Master.  There may be a better way of doing this.  If so, please let me know, too.